# Using window.open, document.open, and document.write to display XML (XML rendering gone)

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, window

This is related to another question, but is **not** a duplicate.
It deals with a proposed solution that I have reached an impasse.

I have the following code that reads an XML, makes changes, opens a window, and writes the XML into the document. The problem is that the content is not rendered as XML. 
Any way to set a content type, etc, to have the browser handle the content as XML?

```
<script>
var wxml;
var xDoc;
var xDevices, xInputs;
var xDevice, xInput;

    function fSetXmlAInput(iDevice, iNode, nodeNewVal) {
      xInput = xInputs[iNode];
      xValue = xInput.getElementsByTagName("value")[0];

      // change node value:
      // console.log("nodeVal: " + xValue.firstChild.nodeValue);
      xValue.firstChild.nodeValue = nodeNewVal;
      // console.log("newVal: " + xValue.firstChild.nodeValue);
    }

    function fSetXmlDevice(iDevice) {
      xDevice = xDevices[iDevice];
      xInputs = xDevice.getElementsByTagName("input");
        fSetXmlAInput(iDevice, 0, "22");
        fSetXmlAInput(iDevice, 1, "33");
    }

    function alternativeLoadXML3() {
        // load xml file
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // IE 5/6
            xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xhttp.open("GET", "my_template.xml", false);
        xhttp.send();

        xDoc = xhttp.responseXML;
        xDevices = xDoc.getElementsByTagName("device");
        fSetXmlDevice(1);

        var xmlText = serializeXmlNode(xDoc);

        var newWindow = window.open("my_template.xml", "Test", "width=300,height=300,scrollbars=1,resizable=1");
        newWindow.document.open();
        newWindow.document.write(xmlText);
        newWindow.document.close()
    };

</script>
```

Below the XML as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<myXmlRoot>
<device>
  <input><name>"name 1"</name><value>{replaceMe!}</value></input>
  <input><name>"name 2"</name><value>{replaceMe!}</value></input>  
</device>
<device>
  <input><name>"name 1"</name><value>{replaceMe!}</value></input>
  <input><name>"name 2"</name><value>{replaceMe!}</value></input>  
</device>
<device>
  <input><name>"name 1"</name><value>{replaceMe!}</value></input>
  <input><name>"name 2"</name><value>{replaceMe!}</value></input>  
</device>
</myXmlRoot>
```

Any way to force the browser to render content in new window as XML...or does using document.open and document.write mean code is rendered as HTML?

Related: [Change XML content using JavaScript, missing refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296845/change-xml-content-using-javascript-missing-refresh/16397896#16397896)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [document.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.open) and `document.write` are used to write HTML or Javascript to a document. This goes back to the [DOM Level 2 Specification of document.open](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-72161170), which assumes that the document is opened in order to write unparsed HTML.

Instead of using `document.open` and `document.write`, I would instead suggest dymanically adding elements using the XML DOM as in `sampleElement.appendChild(XMLnode)`

A similar question can also be found here: [how to display xml in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349250/how-to-display-xml-in-javascript)

Comment: So how would you use `sampleElement.appendChild(XMLnode)` in the above example?

Comment: You would need to load `my_template.xml` using an XML Parser like you have used in function `alternativeLoadXML3()`. Then, you can use the XML DOM to append elements to the document. Finally, to display the XML as a collapsable tree, you can use a JavaScript framework such as those suggested at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366179/how-to-display-xml-in-a-html-page-as-a-collapsible-and-expandable-tree-using-jav

Answer (score 3):

Use dataURI to write xml into new window is very easy.

```js
window.open('data:text/xml,'+encodeURIComponent(xmlText),
     "Test", "width=300,height=300,scrollbars=1,resizable=1");
```

Comment: You legend. Works great in Chrome (not tested in other browsers)